# How to Background time/IO-consuming operations across a firewall in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, impersonation, firewall

**Summary**
We have an ASP.NET application that allows users to query a SQL Server Database through a middle layer (pretty standard stuff). When the user attempts to generate a PDF for the rows that were returned to them. Each set of rows with a common identifier will "turn into" a separate page in the resulting PDF.

Originally, I assumed that the number of rows would be of an order of magnitude that was conducive to piping the end PDF into the ASP Response stream and letting the user download the file to their machine, but newer requirements indicate that the number of rows is very large and vastly outside of the scale for which I had designed this.

My current solution is as follows:

1. If the returned row count is larger than a configured `threshold` value, the user gets a message that asks whether or not they want to generate the PDF's in the background and be notified by email with a URL when its done, so they can download them.
2. If acceptable to the user, I create two `DataTable`s: One with the actual data, and one with MetaData such as where to save the resulting PDF, the name, and other meta-type information.
3. I can then use `DataTable.WriteXML` to generate a "job" file in a particular folder.
4. This is all done in a separate Thread, so the User can continue doing what they want.

**Problem**:
I really want to store the job xml file on a machine inside our firewall (shared network folder), but It seems I cannot for security reasons. I have been told I might want to use Impersonation and have tried but could not get it to work.

The other part of this application is something that "listens in" to the "input" folder, and processes these "job" files once every hour (or similar schedule), moves the generated PDF file to the requisite location and emails the user.

I have gotten the part that reads job files and generates the PDF working, and the part that creates the job files works (when I run it inside the firewall), but when I run it outside the firewall, even attempting impersonation, it does not work. (keeps saying "Network location not found".

**Question(s):**
Am I going about this the right way?
How do I write these files across the firewall?
Any design ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which side of the firewall is the SQL Server / Web server on ? (I am presuming it is on the outside?)

Comment: The SQL Server is inside the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this was to create a table called **PDFJobs** on our database.

This table contained the *Criteria used to run the report* as well as the *desired template folder* and *file*, the *target folder* and *filename* for the resulting PDF. 


I then wrote a command line tool (**PDFGenerator**) which reads from this table, and for each row, creates a separate thread which performs the PDF generation. Once the PDF is generated, it sends an email out to an email address (also contained in the table).


Then I have a windows scheduled task which runs that **PDFGenerator** tool every hour.

It's not idea, but it does the job.

A recent update is that they want something that will trigger the **PDFGenerator** whenever a job row is created...I guess I will have to do some more thinking about that one.

Answer (score 1):

Can you at least do http across the firewall? Then don't create an XML file, but call a webservice that is inside the firewall. Idealy, this web service would not create an XML file either, but instead put the data in a messagequeue. MSMQ Could be useful here.
The PDF generator would then read the XML off this queue.
This way you won't run into the situation where the generator picks up a file that is not complete yet. And you don't waste time and resources polling for files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a nice idea, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Nice to hear that. If you want to make it real fancy, look into WCF. WCF does à good job writing to and reading from an msmq queue.

Comment: As much as I wanted to make it fancy, the time constraints and managerial attention were restrictions. I was not allowed to use MSMQ for various reasons, one of which was that we have another tool that heavily uses this and any use of MSMQ would be seen as potential impact. I solved this in another way, which I will detail below.

Comment: That's how these things go. There are are other ways of notifying your pdfgenerator that it has new work. I once used a UDF broadcast.. You don't have any persistence of the event that way, but you could leave the poll loop in place, in case you miss a signal, perhaps when the generator isn't running.

Comment: What is a UDF broadcast? I tried googling it and could not discern anything in this context. Can you give me some more insight into this method or maybe some hints...thanks for your comments : )

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant UDP broadcast. This is a very low level way of sending a signal across the network. But seriously, I would not do that again today. You don't want to tie your business code to something that dependent on network topology. A UDP broadcasts will probably not be propagated by routers, proxies, etc.